# replaceWith but permanent - another way to store

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div which I update with a count of contents of a shopping cart - when a user adds to the cart, i count the number of lines, then update the div to say e.g. 2 Lines

I currently use:

```
<script type="text/javaScript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#lines2").replaceWith($('#lines').html());
});
</script>
```

I use replace with as I say "0 Items" at the start of a user session.

All works great apart from when user leaves the cart page, the div then changes back to 0 Items - is there a way to rewrite a div more permanently?

I know its a hack but its a favour for a favour thingy!

Comment: what you need is probably [cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie). there is no way of making div "permanent" by itself. You can either update part of the page only (AJAX) or store information about products on client's side - the second one is easier and one way to achieve it is by ussing a cookie. By the way, you need to store the information about what items have been added

Comment: Damn, a cookie, of course! Doh! Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look into session storage and local storage a little better security wise than cookies overall and is supported on all major browsers, check this example
http://html5demos.com/storage
fill in the fields and refresh the browser, check the source code it's pretty straightforward

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible for jQuery to "write a div more permanently".  For items to persist across pages you'd need to set a cookie or a session.

Look into jquery cookie() plugin... this will help accomplish what you are looking to do.

http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2010/09/jquery-cookies-getsetdelete-plugin.html#jQuery-Cookie-plugin

This will help in getting data to persist across pages.  Hope this helps.